# SimpleXML parsing not working with @ElementList

Tags: java, xml, parsing, exception, simple-framework

I'm struggling with this parsing for few hours so I thought maybe you will have insights.
I got this XML structure:

```
<ItemSearchResponse>
     <OperationRequest>...</OperationRequest>
     <Items>
         <Request>
              <IsValid>true</IsValid>
         </Request>
         <TotalPages>16</TotalPages>
         <Item>
              <DetailPageURL>http://....</DetailPageURL>
         </Item>
          <Item>....</Item>
           ...
           <Item>....</Item>
     </Items>
</ItemSearchResponse>
```

My classes are:

```
Root(strict=false)
public class ItemSearchResponse {

    @ElementList
    List<Item> Items;
}
```

and:

```
@Root
public class Item {
    @Element(name="DetailPageURL", required = false)
    private String url;
}
```

when I run below code:

```
InputStream is = ... // stream from xml;
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
ItemSearchResponse response = serializer.read(ItemSearchResponse.class, is);
```

I get below exception:

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'IsValid' does not have a match in class club.mymedia.shoppingadvisor.amazon.xml.Item at line 1
```

It seems that the parsing of `<Item>` didn't work and it parsed `<Request>` instead. 
What should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        InputStream source = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("myxml.xml");
        ItemSearchResponse itemSearchResponse = serializer.read(ItemSearchResponse.class, source);
    }
}

@Root
class ItemSearchResponse {
    @Element(name = "Items")
    Items items;

    @Element(name = "OperationRequest")
    String operationRequest;
}

class Items {

    @Element(name = "Request")
    Request request;

    @Element(name = "TotalPages")
    int totalPages;

    @ElementList(inline = true, name = "Item")
    List<Item> itemList;
}

class Request {

    @Element(name = "IsValid")
    boolean isValid;
}

@Root(name = "Item")
class Item {

    @Element(name = "DetailPageURL", required = false)
    String url;
}
```

Don't forget the java naming convention to have variables starting with lowercase, also variable names should not start with underscore _ or dollar sign $ characters.

Also consider making the fields private and using getters for proper encapsulation as per OOP principles (just saying, not sure if you do)

Comment: The problem is that I have many <item> tags... I need list of them.

Comment: hope it helps :-)

Comment: Works like a charm!
Can you please explain:
1. why you added 'name' attribute in the class Item.
2. why itemList is marked with attribute 'inline'?

Comment: glad to hear :) the name property represents the name of the XML element, and inline means that the elements are not enclosed in any parent element. note that they need to be placed one after another

Comment: I updated my answer with the another way to achieve without inline = true

Comment: I think previous answer was better because I don't have control on the xml - it is given so I cannot change it.

Comment: Can you please update your answer to be like the original one - that was the correct answer, currently it is not :(